# Route params link did not redirect

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, router, react-router-dom

**Hi Please i pass route parameter in a React URL Path but when i am in the same page of route and redirect to another profile he don't redirect**

**didn't know the problem**

**please help**

**Exemple i am in profil "Melek" when i click for another profile "Ahmed" url is changed but did'nt redirect**

[image]
[image]

**This is my code**

this is Route

```
const MainRouter = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar/>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route  exact path="/reset-password/:resetPasswordToken" component={ResetPassword} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/post/create" component={NewPost}/>
                <Route exact path="/post/:postId" component={Post}/>
                <Route exact path="/users" component={Users}/>
                <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup}/>
                <Route exact path="/signin" component={Signin}/>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/findpeople" component={FindPeople}/>
                <Route exact path="/user/:userId" component={Profile}/>
            </Switch>
        </div>
    )
}
```

this is Link

`` <Link to={`/user/${person._id}`} className="row mb-2"> {person.name} </Link> ``

**Please what is the problem i need solution**

Comment: Past full code of `Route` file would help

Comment: i edited i pass full code

Answer (score 0):

I find Solution to force the component to re-mount with change the key prop

i just changed component to render and added Date.now() to the render of route page

```
<Route exact  path="/user/:userId" render={props => <Profile key={Date.now()}  {...props} />} />
```